# how to get ServiceNow records by date in Python API request?

Tags: python-3.x, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm running this Python script request to a ServiceNow API. How can I retrieve just the records updated in the last two days?

The script is running in production that gets all records, but the number of records is growing and I don't need all of them.

```
params_list = {
'sysparm_exclude_reference_link': 'true',
'sysparm_query': 'ORDERBYsys_created_on',
'sysparm_fields': fields,
'sysparm_display_value':'true'
}

res = requests.get(URL_request, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(params.username, params.password), params=params_list)
```

I've tried looking at the documentation but it's all about REST API. I don't know how to translate that to this request.

Answer (score 1):

`'sysparm_query': 'sys_updated_onRELATIVEGT@hour@ago@48^ORDERBYsys_created_on`'